# How to write six possible iterated integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I want to write out all the possible six iterated integrals for finding the volume of region in the first octant enclosed by the $ x^2+z^2=4 $ and the plane $y=3$.

How can I plot this region of integration in *Mathematica* and how to write the six permutations to find volume of the given region.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Six"? Why six" Why not two, three or 224? Where did you take that number from?! And also: have you already tried anything at all?

Comment: @DonAntonio Sir I know that $x^2+y^2=4$ is circular cylinder whose axis is $y$, and the plane $y=3$ is cutting the cylinder, I also know about how to find out the limit of integration, but how to plot this region, I don't know!
So help me please if you can!

Comment: @DonAntonio Sir the cylider axis is $y$ axis because $x^2+z^2=4$, its by mistake that I have written in comment $x^2+y^2=4$
I want to write all six type because I can change the order of integration if the limits are constants easily
But I am facing  trouble in this case, that's why Sir!

Comment: You're completely right: I saw $\;x^2+y^2=4\;$ in your comment but in the question is $\;x^2+z^2=4\;$ ...fine. Now, you keep on saying "six" and now it is "six types"....and I don't really know what you mean.

Comment: Questions about lotting in Mathematica belong to mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DonAntonio: Presumably the number six refers to the six possible orders of integration (i.e., the six permutations of the three variables $x$, $y$, $z$).

Comment: @HansLundmark Yeah of course you are right sir!

Comment: You said in a comment " I also know about how to find out the limit of integration". Does that mean that you had no trouble writing down the six iterated integrals? If you have had trouble, please explain what your thoughts have been so far and where you're getting stuck, so that we can see that you've put effort into the question and how best to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so fast: mechanodroid's answer doesn't actually answer the question presented, to set up each of the possible iterated integrals for the six possible orders of $x,y,z$. It only answers the question about providing a picture.

As a convention, I will label each in order from inside to outside. In inequality form, our region is the intersection of the regions defined by $0\le x$, $0\le y\le 3$, $0\le z$, and $x^2+z^2\le 4$.
$x,y,z$: With $x$ innermost, the bounds there are $0\le x\le \sqrt{4-z^2}$. The bounds for $y$ are unaffected by $z$, and $z$ can range from $0$ to $2$.
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} 1\,dx\,dy\,dz$$
$x,z,y$: With $x$ innermost, the bounds there are $0\le x\le \sqrt{4-z^2}$. The bounds for $z$ are unaffected by $y$, and $y$ can range from $0$ to $3$.
$$\int_0^3 \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} 1\,dx\,dz\,dy$$
$y,x,z$: With $y$ innermost, its bounds are just $0\le y\le 3$ as always. Then $0\le x\le \sqrt{4-z^2}$ and $0\le z\le 2$.
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} \int_0^3 1\,dy\,dx\,dz$$
$y,z,x$:  With $y$ innermost, its bounds are just $0\le y\le 3$ as always. Then $0\le z\le \sqrt{4-x^2}$ and $0\le x\le 2$.
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_0^3 1\,dy\,dz\,dx$$
$z,x,y$: With $z$ innermost, its bounds are $0\le z\le \sqrt{4-x^2}$. Then $0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y\le 3$.
$$\int_0^3 \int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} 1\,dz\,dx\,dy$$
$z,y,x$: With $z$ innermost, its bounds are $0\le z\le \sqrt{4-x^2}$. Then $0\le y\le 3$ and $0\le x\le 2$.
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} 1\,dz\,dy\,dx$$

This is a pretty simple one in how things interact; the only thing that changes any of the limits is which one of $x$ and $z$ is farther in. As such, it's rather redundant, and I was using a lot of copy/paste there.
Evaluating the integrals? I'll leave that to you, if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

The volume is given by three iterated integrals:
$$V = \int_{y=0}^3 \int_{z=0}^2 \int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}dx\,dz\,dy = 3\int_{z=0}^2 \sqrt{4-z^2}\,dz = 3\pi$$

Indeed, we can plot this in Mathematica with `Plot3D[Sqrt[4 - z^2], {y, 0, 3}, {z, 0, 2}]`:

[image]

Comment: Sir can you explain geometrically please!

Comment: @NoorAslam Your region is one half of a cylinder with radius $2$ and height $3$. The rectangle separating the cylinder in half is $[0,3] \times [-2,2]$ in the $yz$-plane. The "height" in the $x$-direction over a point $(y,z) \in [0,3] \times [-2,2]$ can go from $0$ to the boundary of the cylinder, which is given by $x^2+z^2=4$, or $x = \sqrt{4-z^2}$.

Comment: Sir thanks I did not gain it completely because sketch is not before    my eyes but I try to sketch it in mathematica.

Comment: @NoorAslam I have added a plot in Mathematica.

Comment: @Thank you so much mechanodroid Sir!

Comment: A quibble: the region was restricted to the first octant. There shouldn't be any negative $z$ values in there.

Comment: @jmerry Whoops, thanks for the correction.